# Does an Entity–Attribute–Value table (EAV table) need a separate ID field as primary key or composite primary key (like entityId+attributeId)?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, entity-attribute-value

Here's my EAV table structure (I know EAV is bad but number of attributes I need to store are in over ten thousand, so a normalized table isn't going to work)

```
Table name - propertyAssign

entityId - int - indexed
attributeId - smallint - composite index with valueId
valueId - smallint - composite index with attributeId
```

I only need to query this table in two ways.

1. select attributeId, valudId from propertyAssign where entityId=x
2. select entityId from propertyAssign where attributeId=x and valueId=y

So I've added indexes accordingly.

Question => Do I need to add any primary key in here?

Comment: Is the couple (attributeId, valuedId) unique?

Comment: Are you referencing this table from other tables aka FK to this table ?

Comment: @Horia No, not referencing from any other table, no FK. Only using this table in the two scenarios I mentioned.

Comment: @Renzo entityId + attributeId is unique

Comment: So, different entities cannot have the same combination of attributes and values?

Comment: @Renzo one entity can have one attribute only once. Different entity can have same combination of attribute + value.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renzo's answer covers Select #1, but not

```
select entityId from propertyAssign where attributeId=x and valueId=y
```

That needs

```
INDEX(attributeId, valueId, entityId)
```

It will be

- Efficient because it perfectly handles the `WHERE` clause, and
- Even more efficient because the `INDEX` contains all the fields needed ("Covering index").

Yes, that essentially doubles the size of the table (data+PK, then index that contains all the data).  But it is *much* better than having to do a table scan for Select #2.

It smells like `attributeId` and `valueId` are links to 'normalization' tables that have the actual string and value??  Where's the `JOIN` needed to complete the code?  If you are doing it in a separate `SELECT`, then that is less efficient than a `JOIN` because it is two (or three?) roundtrips to the server.

EAV is a really bad design pattern; good luck.

**Edit**

The two `SELECTs` mentioned will benefit from these two indexes:

```
 INDEX(entityId, attributeId, valueId) -- for Select #1
 INDEX(attributeId, valueId, entityId) -- for Select #2
```

And, since that triple is UNIQUE, one or the other `INDEX` may as well be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Now, to pick which...

When `INSERTing`, having the PK start with `entityId` makes it so that all the triples for an entity are 'clustered' together.  This speeds up both the `INSERT` and `SELECT` #1.  So I vote for it being the PK.  Making the other one the PK will not speed up the `INSERTs`.  This is because the creation of an entity with lots of attributes will lead to lots of scattered writes.

Each of the two `SELECTs` is optimally handled by one or the other index; so the `SELECTs` are as fast as possible.  Well, I am ignoring that fact that you normalized the attribute names and values.  This my bite you later, and make for uglier queries.

I say it is a bad design partially because of a benchmark of a very similar schema.  The stress test populated the tables with more than could be cached. The insert rate could not go beyond 7 entities per second.  And that was with the RAID-striped disks running at full capacity.  The normalized attributes, etc, were leading to *lots* of random disk hits.

Comment: I believe you are suggesting this index + PK which Renzo suggested. In that case, Is there any particular reason for including entityId in this index as well? Since first query was already taken care of with PK's index.

Comment: I have understood and experienced EAV is bad design but since attributes are huge in number and very dynamic, I can't use each as column as well. I am not a DB guy, so there is a learning curve for me. I'll continue to look for better solution and replace EAV then.

Comment: What storage engine would you suggest for this table? myisam or innodb? It's kind of write once, read more operations. Once I've stored attributes of any particular entity, I don't need to edit/delete it any further, only query them with different criteria I mentioned.

Comment: If server configuration also contributes in making call, I've dedicated server with 24G ram, so good amount of caching available.

Comment: (continued) And current table size is around 5-6G (only data, not index) and I think it'll increase by another 50% as I process remaining data in coming days.

Comment: InnoDB for virtually all uses these days.  Including your tables.

Comment: Assuming nothing much else running on that machine, `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G`

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Given the queries that you have to execute, I think that the best thing to do is the following:

1. remove the index over `entityId`;
2. declare as primary key all three attributes (in order `entityId, attributeId, valueId`, without introducing an explicit (surrogate) primary key.

The primary key declaration will cause the creation of composite index over `entityId, attributeId, valueId`.

This has two effects:

1. can reduces problems due to lack of a primary key (for an example of problems see for instance [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/18/innodb-scalability-issues-tables-without-primary-keys/)), and
2. it will speed up the queries of the first type (`select attributeId, valudId from propertyAssign where entityId=x`), since the access plan could use only the index to give the result of the query.

Comment: If I am positive that even without primary key, I won't be inserting duplicates, do I still need to add primary key in this particular case? There are two reasons for asking this question - 1) My table has millions rows, so if not needed, it'll be waste of server resources 2) I had read somewhere that if you don't have primary key in the table, underlying engine will creates some hidden structure to manage inserts, so not adding primary key won't save space.

Comment: Ok, in this case, and given the queries that you have to execute, I think that the best thing to do is to remove the index over entity and declare as primary key all three attributes, that will insert a composite index over `entityId, attributeId, valueId`. This has two effects: 1) can reduces problems due to lack of a primary key (see for instance [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/18/innodb-scalability-issues-tables-without-primary-keys/)), and 2) speed up the queries of the first type (`select attributeId, valudId from propertyAssign where entityId=x`).

Comment: Thanks Renzo. Even if I remove index from entityId and add "composite" primary key, will the db use this composite primary key/index when searching records with just entityId? (since there are millions rows, need to make sure of that)

Comment: @Mihir yes, composite indexes can be used every time you do a query with a condition on any *prefix* of the key, so both for query only on entityId or for entityId and attributeId (for this reason is important to specify the key attributes in the right order!). Moreover, the index can be used to find the result of a query by using an access plan with the IndexOnlyFilter operator, which is very convenient since the table must not be accessed. In any case you can use EXPLAIN to see if indexes are used on not, which indexes are used, etc.

Comment: If your table is InnoDB, having an explicit `PRIMARY KEY` does _not_ waste resources.  In fact, it _saves_ resources by not forcing InnoDB to fabricate a hidden 6-byte PK.  InnoDB _must_ have a PK.

Comment: @RickJames I had read something like that, that's why I was wondering if I should add PK or not. Thanks. And yes, my table is InnoDB

Comment: It is always(?) better to have an _explicit_ PK for an InnoDB table.  (I have the '?' because there may be some obscure case I have not thought about.)  I have been burned a few times by not having a PK.

Comment: Whether to have a 'natural' PK (when available) or add an artificial `AUTO_INCREMENT` -- this choice depends on many factors.